# why can't i use parentheses in codeigniter join query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

hi i am using codeigniter join

```
$this->db->join
```

i used

```
$this->db->join ( $table2 . " as c","( c.3rdPartyID=a.ShopID OR c.3rdPartyID=a.ParentID OR c.ShopID=a.ShopID OR c.ShopID=a.ParentID )  AND c.3rdPartyID !=0 ", 'left' );
```

and i also tried with

```
$join_query = "( c.3rdPartyID=a.ShopID OR c.3rdPartyID=a.ParentID OR c.ShopID=a.ShopID OR c.ShopID=a.ParentID )  AND c.3rdPartyID !=0 ";

$this->db->join ( $table2 . " as c",$join_query, 'left' );
```

it gives an error .

but with out parentheses it works fine , like this

```
$this->db->join ( $table2 . " as c"," c.3rdPartyID=a.ShopID OR c.3rdPartyID=a.ParentID OR c.ShopID=a.ShopID OR c.ShopID=a.ParentID   AND c.3rdPartyID !=0 ", 'left' );
```

but in my case i need parentheses , should i go to normal mysql queries , **is codeignier incapable** of doing this , please help...

this is the error

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Use `false`. Ex:

```
$this->db->join ( $table2 . " as c","( c.3rdPartyID=a.ShopID OR c.3rdPartyID=a.ParentID OR c.ShopID=a.ShopID OR c.ShopID=a.ParentID )  AND c.3rdPartyID !=0 ", 'left', false );
```

Comment: people should think once before upvote and think twice before downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Either

1) move your "AND c.3rdPartyID !=0" to a separate ->where()

or

2) write your query & use:

```
$sql = "Select...";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: if you think it should work, please output the full sql statement using $this->db->last_query() and post it here for us to see

Answer (score 0):

Copied from ellislab forum:

> That query will not be possible using the Active Record join()
>   function.  There is a line of regular expressions that looks for a
>   certain structure of a join condition (table.something =
>   table.somethingelse typically).  It will ignore any characters other
>   than alphanumeric and periods (.) when recreating the first part of
>   the join statement you provide.  Part of the reason of this is Active
>   Record employs a private function called _protect_identifiers, which
>   adds any necessary info to a column name
>   (hostname.database.table.column) in the case that it is required (see
>   file ‘DB_driver.php’ inside the Database system folder for a better
>   description).  Adding in additional characters before the table.column
>   would cause those characters to be in the middle of the column name
>   structure, in the event a host or database name need to be added to
>   it.
>
> So basically, you can’t use the join() function as it stands.  You can
>   use the query() function and write it out fully yourself, or extend
>   the Active Record class and rewrite the join() function to suit your
>   needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    $this->db->from ( $table2 . " as c"," join on ( c.3rdPartyID=a.ShopID OR c.3rdPartyID=a.ParentID OR c.ShopID=a.ShopID OR c.ShopID=a.ParentID )  AND c.3rdPartyID !=0 ");
```